# creating a child inside a child in firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, bitmap

I have a Realtime Database that has the values of a group code. I want that the codes will be like a firebase of its own, including bitmaps of images, something like that:

[image: my desired Realtime Database],

how can I do that?

I tried to do:

```
databaseReference.child("CODES").child(groupCode).child(bitMapToString(mBitmap)).setValue(mBitmap);
```

and

```
databaseReference.child("CODES").child(groupCode).setValue(mBitmap);
```

but neither of those work

```
    {
        String groupCode=this.getArguments().getString("groupNum");
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
        {





                    Uri chosenImageUri = data.getData();

                    Bitmap mBitmap = null;
                    try {
                       mBitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(requireActivity().getContentResolver(), chosenImageUri);
                       Map<String, Object> codes = new HashMap<>();
                        codes.put(bitMapToString(mBitmap), true);

                        DatabaseReference db=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
                        DatabaseReference groupCodeRef = db.child("CODES").child(groupCode);
                        groupCodeRef.setValue(codes);
```

this is the code i have, and it just doesnt work. if i remove the part from the map until the end it will work, so the problem is in the insertion

this is bitMapToString:

```
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
        byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
        String temp = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
        return temp;
    }
```

Comment: To understand better, do you want to add a Bitmap image itself inside the Realtime Database or only the URL of the image?

Comment: @AlexMamo i want to add the bitmap value of the picture. the picture itself will be displaid outside of the database. i need to store just the chacrctes themself

Comment: So you want to store multiple numbers under the same node, right?

Comment: @AlexMamo correct

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store multiple values under the `41947781` node, then you have to add key-values pairs right under it. To achieve that using Java, please check the code below:

```
Map<String, Object> codes = new HashMap<>();
codes.put("bitmap1", true);
codes.put("bitmap2", true);
codes.put("bitmap3", true);

DatabaseReference db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference groupCodeRef = db.child("CODES").child(groupCode);
groupCodeRef.setValue(codes);
```

I also recommend you attach a listener to the setValue() operation, to see if something goes wrong.

The above code will create a structure that looks like this:

```
db
|
--- CODES
     |
     --- 41947781
           |
           --- bitmap1: true
           |
           --- bitmap2: true
           |
           --- bitmap3: true
```

It's true we could add the codes into an array rather then in a map, but I recommend you read the following resource:

- [Best Practices: Arrays in Firebase](https://firebase.blog/posts/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase/)

Comment: the bit maps im putting are those which the user selected from the galleris, so it will only be added one at a time. is it ok?
and also can i put the bitmap themself or do i have to move them to string?

Comment: it doesnt work, it just colapses

Comment: If you can't get the approach Alex described to work, please edit your question and add the code that reproduces where you got stuck.

Comment: @YoavHofstein Yes, you can add them one at a time. However, the Realtime Database is not designed to store the bitmaps themself, but [Cloud Storage of Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage) is indeed designed for that.

Comment: @YoavHofstein Hey Yoav. Did my answer/comments help? Can I help you with other information?

Comment: unfortently your code didnt work. i have no idea what if firebase cloud storage, but i will loke into it. thanks

Comment: "your code didn't work" doesn't provide enough information so I can further help. What exactly didn't work? Did you have any errors? However, Cloud Storage for Firebase sounds like the solution for you, right?